# Make a bet on/of/from £10

Tags: grammar, prepositions, collocation

> Me & my flatmate have made a bet [on/of/from] £10 that you'll send me a selfie but she doesn't believe that.

I've been struggling with this sentence. Which preposition should I use out of on, of and from?

Comment: It's a bet **of** £10. However, you bet **on** a horse.

Comment: Just use "made a £10 bet", which is a common construction.

Comment: @Mick Or alternatively a bet _for_ $10 (with standard conversion fees for what I have a suspicion is a more commonly used preposition in AmE).

Comment: as an American English speaker, I would never say "bet on $10" or " bet from $10".  But a few months ago I made a $100 bet with a friend, betting *on* Trump. or, a  bet *of* $100 *on* Trump.

Comment: Okay. So if I say "me & my friend have made a £10 bet that you'll send me a selfie". It is correct now, right?

Comment: Why has no-one noticed that "Me and my flatmate" should be "My flatmate and I" yet?